# Why is /etc/fstab not being used on boot?

Tags: rhel, mount, nfs, fstab, oracle-linux

I have an nfs device mounted.  I am trying to set it with `nosuid` through `/etc/fstab`, but I am having trouble.  I have set `/etc/fstab` correctly (I think), but here's the issue.  When I reboot the system and run `mount | grep nfs`, I can see that it's not mounted with `nosuid`.  Then, when I run `umount -l sunrpc`, and then `mount sunrpc`, it mounts correctly with `nosuid`.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Command:

```
# mount |grep nfs
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
# umount -l sunrpc
# mount sunrpc
# mount |grep nfs
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,nosuid)
```

/etc/fstab

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Apr 19 09:13:00 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_opendcsoel6-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=e3b1a0fb-c27f-42e9-ab93-15295497a293 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_opendcsoel6-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
sunrpc  /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs         rpc_pipefs      nosuid  0       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are mixing **rpc_pipefs** with **nfs**.

rpc_pipefs is helper necessary for nfs operation but it is not actual mount of remote nfs server. Most of the time it can be safely omitted from /etc/fstab (usually proper defaults for rpc_pipefs are hardcoded in nfs startup script which ignores /etc/fstab).

For example the following line is from my /etc/fstab (note **nfs** instead of **rpc_pipefs** in 3-rd column):

```
192.168.200.1:/mnt/vg/git   /mnt/host/git   nfs  defaults       0 0
192.168.200.1:/mnt/vg/work  /mnt/host/work  nfs  nosuid,noexec  0 0
```

Comment: Ahh, I see - This is interesting, I didn't know that.  That would explain why it only works when I unmount and remount it.  I will do a little more research, but if my findings are the same, I'll mark this one correct. Thank!